# Character Z Rotation

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, geometry

I know this is a really stupid question, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

```
var x = pressed('left') - pressed('right') // obvious (0 = nope, 1 = left, -1 = right)
var z = pressed('up')   - pressed('down' ) // also obvious
player.rotation.y = somehowGetRotationInRadians;
```

Thing is, I'm too stupid to know how to get the character's rotation from those two variables. I bet there is some averaging and π involved, but I have no idea how.

<sup><sub>I don't know how relevant the tags are.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be more specific in current state your question does not make much sense

- it implies you want to control some object (player) by arrow keystrokes
- I assume 2D for now

so what you need is:

1. object position and orientation data

   ```
       struct plr_object
        {
        double x,y; // position in pixels or meters or whatever
        double a;   // angle in radians
        } plr;
   ```

   - this must be persistent so global or static variable ...
   - or locally global variable
   - or reference to it
2. on keyboard event (or in some timer)

   ```
       double da=5.0*M_PI/180.0; // rotation speed
       double dl=5.0; // movement speed
       bool _redraw=false;
       // handle rotation
       if (pressed('left' )) { plr.a+=da; redraw=true; }
       if (pressed('right')) { plr.a-=da; redraw=true; }
       // handle movement
       if (pressed('up'   )) { plr.x+=dl*cos(plr.a); plr.y+=dl*sin(plr.a); redraw=true; }
       if (pressed('down' )) { plr.x-=dl*cos(plr.a); plr.y-=dl*sin(plr.a); redraw=true; }
       if (_redraw) redraw the scene ...
   ```
3. redraw

   - in redraw you have to handle angle of the object
   - so it is draw rotated
   - use transform matrix for that or if your object is just some easy GDI like
   - circle+line then just draw the direction significant part rotated.